# Arbitrary EXT4-fs remounts scattered throughout dmesg output

Tags: ext4

I've been trying to diagnose a message I see in my dmesg output. Last night I was watching a video which really taxed my notebook and I noticed that the computer was super hot and the fan wouldn't stop blasting away at full speed, even after I rebooted. At anyrate, last night and again this morning I am seeing messages withing my dmesg output to the effect of:

**EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0**

and occassionally it'll do a doublt remount with the primary remount listed with commit=600

Now this may be another issue but I thought I might mention it because they could be related, but I am also seeing this message frequently within my output:

**composite sync not supported**

I looked within syslog to see if I could see any indication of what might be causing this but I see nothing. This seem completely random. Is there something I can do to determine what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you have a loose power line or bad battery. The message "...,commit=600" is printed when the notebook is unplugged from a power supply. When reconnecting again, it'll print "...,commit=0". This is a power saving feature, to avoid wasting battery power (but at the expense of data loss on power failure), the filesystem does not immediately write away data.

I don't know what the "composite sync not supported" error is referring to.

Comment: Thank you. I think this just my indeed be the issue since I have recently been having issues with the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

see http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1473045.html

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you summarised some of the information from the link you've posted.  As is, it is difficult to know what solution you're suggesting exactly.